# Why does border-bottom property add a scrollbar to vertical axis?

Tags: css

I have used Calc function to adjust header, footer and content one one screen, but after adding border bottom property to footer, scrollbar gets added to vertical axis. Is it suppose to add a scrollbar to vertical axis also?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  header
</div>

<div class="content">
  content
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is *1px* border adds 1px height to the content so the total height becomes 100vh + 1px. Decreasing the height of footer for 1px is the solution.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  /* height: 100px; */
  height: 99px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  header
</div>

<div class="content">
  content
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `box-sixing` in all `html` Element. it's set box as html tag size.

(By using `*{...}` )

#### Add Code

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

#### Full Code

```html
<head>
 <style>
      *
      {
          margin: 0;
          padding:0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .header
      {
          height: 100px;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: pink;
          text-align: center;
      }

      .content
      {
          height: calc(100vh - 200px);
          width: 100%;
          background-color: red;
          text-align: center;

      }

      .footer
      {
          height: 100px;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: orange;
          text-align: center;
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;

      }
        
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
   header
  </div>

  <div class="content">
   content
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
   footer
  </div>
</body>
```